# Find $\dfrac{\Gamma(κ+m/2)}{\Gamma(2κ+m)}$ knowing that $κ$ and $m$ are real numbers?

Tags: calculus

Find $\dfrac{\Gamma(κ+m/2)}{\Gamma(2κ+m)}$ knowing that $κ$ and $m$ are real numbers?

Comment: @Matteo.  Huh?  Why did you return the question to its improperly formatted and very hard to interpret typography?!?

Comment: There is a $\Gamma$ duplication formula: $\Gamma(z)\Gamma(z+1/2)=2^{1-2z}\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma(2z).$

Comment: @DavidG.Stork The edit is valid, he only removed your $\{\kappa,m\}\in\Bbb R$. Better use words than an incorrect formula.

Comment: I used the duplication formula, but I need to simplify it and the result dont contain factorial and Gamma function

Comment: Your expression simplifies to $\dfrac{\Gamma(x)}{\Gamma(2x)}$ where $x=\kappa+m/2$, but it's not very helpful.

Comment: Yes Bro, but we can't caluculate the factorial of a real

Comment: What makes you think there's a simplification for general real numbers that doesn't contain gamma function?

Comment: What is \dfrac{\Gamma(n)}{\Gamma(2n)} for n\in\mathbb{N}?

Comment: @Mathematics:  *PLEASE* learn how to use *MathJax* so you can set your equations properly.  Your original question and this note are incoherent and waste others' time.